# How to rename a variable in a loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Can somebody please tell if there exists a way to rename a variable in each iteration of a loop in MATLAB?

Actually, I want to save a variable in a loop with a different name incorporating the index of the loop. Thanks.

Comment: Make a vector `foo` of appropriate size and store in `foo(loopidx)`?

Comment: @MarcClaesen, Hi Marc. Thanks, but this is not the way that I want. It should be something like: var_i, where 'i' is the current index of the loop. I need to store each of these variables in a MAT file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on your comment, I suggest using a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/cell.html). This allows any type of result to be stored by index. For example:

```
foo=cell(bar,1);
for ii=1:bar
    foo{ii}=quux;
end
```

You can then save `foo` to retain all your intermediate results. Though the loop index is not baked into the variable name as you want, this offers identical functionality.

Comment: +1: ...in most cases, it is better to avoid eval, because sometimes eval is evil...

Answer (score 8):

Ignoring the question, "why do you need this?", you can use the [`eval()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) function:

Example:

```
for i = 1:3
  eval(['val' num2str(i) '=' num2str(i * 10)]);
end
```

The output is:

```
val1 =
    10

val2 =
    20

val3 =
    30
```

Comment: Although this is possible, it is generally not recommended, see http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F. The answer given by Marc Claesean is the correct way to do this..

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using a struct to save the loop index into the name of the field:

```
for ii=1:bar
    foo.(["var" num2str(ii)]) = quux;
end
```

This creates a structure with fields like `foo.var1`, `foo.var1` etc. This does what you want without using `eval`.