# How can I write different length and different datatypes data to a text file from matlab

Tags: matlab

Right now I can only write a fixed length data to the text file ,but I need to change to a variable length data.
My code:

```
fileID = fopen(logfilePathLocal,'at+');
formatSpec = '%s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n';
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,data{1,:});
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: How does `data` look, can you give an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving/appending output values of varying vector length generated from for loop into separate files in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896829/saving-appending-output-values-of-varying-vector-length-generated-from-for-loop)

Comment: Or [Display cell array contents in another output format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479920/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display cell array contents in another output format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479920/display-cell-array-contents-in-another-output-format)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a variable in a loop in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143025/how-to-rename-a-variable-in-a-loop-in-matlab)

Comment: @hmofrad please explain your [dupe target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143025/how-to-rename-a-variable-in-a-loop-in-matlab)...

Comment: @excaza, [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18143079/5412470) is using a combination of `eval` and array of characters to enable dynamic naming and evaluation. You can reproduce the answer for this question using this post. It was too much of a discussion, so take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%f` instead of `%d`, and specify width and precision, e.g. width 3 and precision 5 would be `%3.5f`.

For more information on specifier syntax, see the [`fprintf` reference](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#btf8xsy-3) in the matlab documentation.

---

**EDIT:** If what you mean instead is that you don't know "how many `%d` my format-string will end up having", you can construct the format-string manually first (e.g. by concatenaton, or by using `sprintf`), and then use the resulting string in `fprintf`, e.g.

```
   N = 5; % number of data, subject to change on each run.

% construct format-string
  s = '%s';
  for i = 1:N-1; s = [s, '%d, ']; end
  s = [s, '%d\n']; % final data point

% use it with fprintf to print your data 
  fprintf (s, 'The data is: ', data{1,:});
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143025/how-to-rename-a-variable-in-a-loop-in-matlab), you can use the combination of `eval` and an array of characters to produce the desired format specification alongside the data entry you're looking to print into a file.

```
clear
clc

fid = fopen('file.txt','at+');

% Generate some random data in a cell
data = {rand(5,1) rand(3,1)};

% Calculate required dimensions for fprintf
% and store the results in file.txt
n = size(data,2);
m = [];
for i=1:n
    m = [m size(data{i},1) - 1];
end
% Finally, we will have n = 2, m = [4 2]

% Produce the final dynamic code snippet
fmt = [];
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m(i)
        fmt = [fmt '%d,'];
    end
    fmt = [fmt '%d\n'];
    eval(['fprintf(fid,fmt,data{' num2str(i) '});']);
    fmt = [];
end
```

An example output which is borrowed from `file.txt` is:

```
9.063082e-01,8.796537e-01,8.177606e-01,2.607280e-01,5.943563e-01
2.251259e-02,4.252593e-01,3.127189e-01
```